How to apply a set of functions to a list of dataframes and save the result as another df list?
I have a list of dataframes containing species counts per year and location. I want to apply two functions to all columns of each dataframe but the first 2.
The 2 functions I want to apply are from the vegan package:

specaccum and
specnumber

I've created two functions that apply each one of Vegan's functions with the needed arguments:
specacc <- function(df) { 
  out <- vegan::specaccum(df[,-c(1,2)], method = "collector")
  out$richness
}


And:
specrich <- function(df) {
  vegan::specnumber(df[,-c(1,2)])
}

With the results of these functions, I want to create another df consisting of a Year (from the original dataframes), a spec_acum(the result of the specacc function) and Richness(the result of the specrich function). Finally, I want to save each dataframe as list element, ideally named after the original list elements.
I'm trying to use a forloop as follows:

test2.lst <- list()

for (i in counts.lst) {
  
  years <- i[2] # this is a tibble.
  yrs <- pull(years, Year)
  spec_acum <- specacc(i)
  richness <- specrich(i)
  df_temp <- rbind(richness, spec_acum)
  df_temp <- as.data.frame(df_temp)
  colnames(df_temp) <- yrs
  df_temp$vars <- row.names(df_temp)
  print(df_temp)
  test2.lst[[i]] <- df_temp[i]
}



I can print all the generated df but I get the following error when trying to save the result:
Error in [[<-(tmp, i, value = df_temp) :  invalid subscript type 'list'
What am I doing wrong?
A MRE can be created from the following code:

# to create the `parent`df

Years <- c(2022, 2023, 2024, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024)
        
Location <- c(rep("A",3), rep("B",9), rep("C",9), rep("D",7), rep("E",9))
        
a <- c(rep(0,13), 2, rep(0, 23))
        
b <- c(rep(0,3),3,11,1,1,2,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,4,0,6,7,0,0,2,0,4,2,2,0,0,0,1,1,2,1,28,2)
        
c <- c(rep(0,30),100,600,rep(0,5))
        
d <- c(rep(0,10),5, rep(0,14),4,1, rep(0,6), rep(3,3),0)
        
e <- c(rep(0,4),20, rep(0,7),150,120,100,600,100,500,500,100,200,290,93,195,0,40,50,0,170,300,0,111,113,470,380,486,30  )
        
counts <- data.frame(Years, Location, a, b, c, d, e)


and

# to create the df `list`

counts.lst <- split(counts, counts$Location)



Hi Pedro! Could you clarify what exactly youre asking here - is your question "how to remove all columns with only 0's from each data frame in a list?" If not, could you clarify what you are looking for? Good luck!

Hi! No. I'm trying to apply 2 functions to a list of dataframes and save the result as another dataframe list
